# mat-error reappears on reset the form angular-material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

In my angular 6 project I have used mat-error of angular-material to show error:

```
<form class="custom-form" name="deal-form">
     <mat-form-field class="full-width">
        <input name="id" type="number" min="0" matInput placeholder="Id" 
            [formControl]="id" required [(ngModel)]="deal.deal_id">
        <mat-error *ngIf="id.invalid">{{getMandatoryErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" *ngIf="!isEdit" (click)="save()">Save</button>
</form>
```

After Click on Save button I save the data and Clear the Reset the form.
Following is my .ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, Validators, AbstractControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-deals',
  templateUrl: './deals.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./deals.component.css']
})
export class DealsComponent implements OnInit {
resetObj(){
        this.deal = new Deal();
    }

save(){
        if(this.validateFields() && !this.invalidSku){
            this.dealService.createDeal(this.deal)
                .subscribe(data=>{
                    this.resetObj();
                })
        }
    }
}
```

After resetting the Object I am getting the mat-error in the form fields.
Though the data is saved properly but mat-error should not appear on clear data. Can anyone suggest me a way to resolve this.

Comment: Not related, but you shouldn't mix ngModel with reactive forms. This is deprecated and will be removed in Angular version 7. You should choose either template-driven or reactive form.

Comment: nb: try to avoid binding functions in your template for performance reasons 
 (ref: `{{getMandatoryErrorMessage()}}`) bind variables instead.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/60544992/11127383, most probably you need to set `type="reset"` to your button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let me explain how `invalid` property works:

You defined an independent `formControl` or included in `formGroup` then you set the value and list of **Validators** like: required, min, email, ..etc.
if the value doesn't match these validators it will still `invalid`.

**What about `mat-error`?**

`mat-error` will be shown (by default) after the user touch the field.

**What happened in your case?**

In your case you're using `ngModel` and `FormControl` so you pass the value using `ngModel` and handle errors of `FormControl`, which is totally wrong; cause you reset the value but you don't reset the `FormControl`, so it's **touched** and `invalid` then the error will be shown.

**How to solve it?**

Remove `ngModel` from `input` and declare a `formControl` called `id` with deal's id value:

```
id: FormControl;

resetObj(){
    this.deal = new Deal();
    id = new FormControl(this.deal.deal_id, [Validators.required, Validator.min(0)]);
}
```

In this case, when you reset the value, you will reset the formControl again which means it will be marked as **untouched**; so mat error will disappear.

**BTW**; you can declare multiple `mat-error`that each one is for specific validator instead of generic `invalid` property, like:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="id.errors?.required">ID is required field</mat-error>
<mat-error *ngIf="id.errors?.min">Minimum value is 0</mat-error>
```